# What does this unusual notification mean?

Tags: iphone

I have received a notification 2 or 3 times in the last week that "Someone has used your phone number to set up a new iPad.  Are you aware of this?"  It only has one option for response at the bottom of the notification -- "OK"  What does this mean?  There is no mention of my password being used.

Comment: [Change your iCloud password immediately.](https://www.icloud.com)

Comment: Could you take a picture or screen shot of the notification? We can help by obscuring personal details if needed. Sounds like spam/phishing, but it could be legit I suppose.